# Removing fixed footer and get imaged below header

Tags: html, css

I got website built from html template. I've been trying to remove footer from fixed position and make images appear at full height  between  header and footer at my index page.  At the moment images are hidden behind header and footer.  My website link http://vizoviphotography.com. 
 Any suggestions how resolve this please?

Comment: Welcome to SO.   It's good practice to post the code that is troubling you.  In your case it will be the HTML and CSS...So if I understand you, you don't want the header to scroll with the page?  That's going to require changing .header {position:fixed} to .header{position:relative;} assuming your header div is called 'header'

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new here and English not my first language. In first post I meant footer not header. Regarding posting HTML and CSS code  I don't know what causing problem exactly and post here entire HTML page would be too much and CSS located in different files as well. So maybe would be easier to look into my index page and tell me what code to post.

Comment: @vizovi, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Your questions are likely to get downvoted and ignored without posting some minimal, functioning examples. This is a Q&A site aimed at helping others who come across your question, not just yourself. So you need to attempt to write your question in a way that benefits the community. Otherwise, there are many other sites you can use to help you learn Web development.

Comment: I'sorry for not posting code here I just don't want to post entyre 5 css stylesheets. I don't know exactly what is related to my issue ... Maybe it's wrong forum for me

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is that you used

```
.epic-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and

```
.epicSlider.slider-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;        /* this really is a problem */
    top: 2px;
    left: 1px;
}
```

These are always going to make the slider fill 100% of the body

firstly you can remove the height:100% from the .epic-wrapper style and make it relative and remove the padding at the top of #wrapper.

```
.epic-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.no-touch #wrapper {
    /* padding-top: 130px; */
}
```

I then suggest that you write a bit of JQuery that hook into "resize" and calculate the height of '.slider-wrapper' dynamically. You will need to get the (body height - (header Height + footer height)) and then apply that calculated value to the height of .epicSlider.slidewrapper (or #epicSlider if you want). Remember to account for margins and borders.

to get something like

```
.epicSlider.slider-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 670px;
    top: 2px;
    left: 1px;
}
```

You need to handle the resize so that when users drag the window around it adjusts height accordingly.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. I don't want to hide header and footer I want images showing  between header and footer 100% height

Comment: Sorry, updated my answer according to your clarification